# How can I run all unit tests of Jinja2?

Tags: python, unit-testing, jinja2

I want to run the unittests of Jinja2 whenever I change something to make sure I'm not breaking something.

There's [a package full of unit tests](http://dev.pocoo.org/projects/jinja/browser/tests). Basically it's a folder full of Python files with the name "test_xxxxxx.py"

How do I run all of these tests in one command?

Comment: I guess it's simpler now than it was 11 years ago. Today, it should be simply `pip install pytest` and the go to the root folder and execute `pytest`. No arguments necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Jinja uses the [py.test testing tool](http://codespeak.net/py/dist/test.html). If so you can run all tests by just running *py.test* from within the tests subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at [nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/) too. It's supposed to be a py.test evolution.

Comment: nose didn't work well with these tests, but thanks for the link non-the-less

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help. You can also take a look at Python Testing Tools Taxonomy ( http://pycheesecake.org/wiki/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy )

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for "test.py" in the Jinja2 package! -- Those are not unit tests!  That is a set of utility functions for checking attributes, etc.   My testing package is assuming that they are unit tests because of the name "test" -- and returning strange messages.

Answer (score -1):

Try to 'walk' through the directories and import all from files like "test_xxxxxx.py", then call unittest.main()

Comment: I know I can essentially write a method that walks the tree and runs the test each after the other. but py.test in the accepted answer already does that and more.